# Oracle JDeveloper 4K Display Resolution issue

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

After running Oracle JDeveloper on my Dell Inspiron Gaming 7567 with 4K Display resolution, I can even barely see the items on the screen - The text, icons & menus are too small for me to even start with development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to Oracle JDeveloper shortcut location -> Properties.

Navigate to **"Compatibility"** tab. Then do the following:

1. (Optionally) Check *"Run this program in compatibility mode for":*  **Windows 7**
2. Select *"Override high DPI scaling behavior. Scaling performed by":*  **System**
3. (Optionally) Check *"Run this program as administrator"*

[image]